# Implementation of Multiclass Perceptron

Tags: matlab, neural-network

The following text is from Hal Daumé III's ["*A Course in Machine Learning*"](http://ciml.info/dl/v0_9/ciml-v0_9-ch03.pdf) online text book (Page-41).

[image]

I implemented the following:

**Is the implementation correct?**

```
D = 2;
MaxIter = 100;
w = zeros(1, D);    
b = 1;
for i=1:MaxIter    
    output = zeros(D,1);        
    for j=1:D   

        a = activ_func(product(x(j,:), w') + b);

        if product(y(j,1), a)>0
            output(j)  = a;

            delta = y(j) - output(j);

            inc = x(j,:) * (coeff  * delta);

            w(1, j) = w(1, j) + inc';

            b = b + y(j, 1);
        end
    end
end

w_ret = w;
```

I have a few confusions.

What does it mean by `ya`? Is it the multiplication of a scalar value of `a` and the entire vector `y`? Or, between `a` and the `j`-th element of `y` (given that the inner for loop uses `j` as the loop counter)?

Also, what does that Algorithm-6 do? It should be calling Algorithm-5 rather than. Right?

Comment: You have not included information about `activ_func`, `product`, `coeff` and `delta` (maybe more, I stopped counting). Please include all the necessary information, it's not possible to help without it.

Comment: This is not multiclass perceptron.